# update multi table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with a same column "token_registrazione", I would update a field if token_registrazione = .... in one operation

Example

```
UPDATE utenti_aziende SET verificato = 2 WHERE token_registrazione = XXX
```

AND

```
UPDATE utenti_privati SET verificato = 2 WHERE token_registrazione = XXX
```

Comment: Why? If you sick 2 queries together and shove them to MySQL in a single command, it's the same amount of work for MySQL. What would you achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this in a single statement for the sake of data integrity?  If so, you should probably roll both UPDATE commands into a single transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE utenti_aziende SET verificato = 2 WHERE token_registrazione = XXX;
UPDATE utenti_privati SET verificato = 2 WHERE token_registrazione = XXX;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea mixing two inserts into one complicated, if it is even possible. Better run both inserts in transaction so you achive that both are executed or none is.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE table1 ...
UPDATE table2 ...
COMMIT
```